# Kafka connect HDFS sink ERROR failed creating a WAL

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using Kafka connect HDFS.
When I'm trying to run my connector I'm got the following exception:

> ERROR Failed creating a WAL Writer: Failed to create file[/path/log] for [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_208312334_41] for client [IP] because this file is already beign create by [DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_165323242_41]

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As per further testing, upgrading the version to 2.7.7 didn't help. We still ran into WAL issue. We ended using a different sink s3SinkConnector.

Comment: I think you need to describe more details of what you did and at least one reason for doing only that. Like the command to clean up.

Comment: As per further testing, upgrading the version to 2.7.7 didn't help. We still ran into WAL issue. We ended using a different sink s3SinkConnector.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the workaround to cleanup the wal logs and connector restart. We are also testing on upgrading the hadoop local version 2.73 to 2.7.7 and the kafka-hdfs version to 5.5 of our sink connector from  Its currently on testing and so far the wal issue is not recoccuring.